# Rounding dates in Python

Tags: python, datetime

Say I am looking at a particular date:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
days_to_substract = 65
my_date = date.today()-timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)
```

How can I find:

1. The date of the `Monday` right before `my_date` (if `my_date` isn't a Monday)
2. The date of the closest `Monday` to `my_date`

Is there a way to round dates in `datetime`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use dateutil

```
from datetime import *
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

days_to_substract = 64
my_date   = (date.today()-timedelta(days=days_to_substract))
next=my_date+relativedelta(weekday=MO)
previous=my_date+relativedelta(weekday=MO(-1))
print ('mydate is %s' %my_date)
print ('next monday is %s' %next)
print ('previous monday is %s' %previous)

diff1=my_date-previous
diff2=next-my_date
if diff2<diff1:
    print ('Closest monday is %s' %next)
else:
    print ('Closest monday is %s' %previous)
```

will output:

```
mydate is 2014-01-21
next monday is 2014-01-27
previous monday is 2014-01-20
Closest monday is 2014-01-20
```

Comment: Isn't it more accurate to say that's the next monday, and closest would be the two of those with the minimum absolute difference?

Answer (score 1):

Use weekday:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
d=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
days_to_substract = 65
my_date = (date.today()-timedelta(days=days_to_substract))
t=my_date.weekday()
print "Today is ",d[t]," Wait ",(6-t+1)," days for Monday"
```

Output:

```
Today is  Monday  Wait  7  days for Monday
```

Comment: `6-t+1` is just `7-t` :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use date.weekday (http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) to find the weekday integer value for "my_date".  Then you could use the difference of the current weekday (ex. weekday = 2 for wednesday) and perform another timedelta calculation.  This worked for me when I tried it:

```
from datetime import *

days_to_subtract = 65
my_date = (date.today() - timedelta(days=days_to_subtract))
dow = my_date.weekday()
monday_my_date = (my_date - timedelta(days=dow))

print(monday_my_date)
```

Good Luck!